# Trying read a Json and a image file from client using Slim Framework

Tags: php, android, json, http, slim

So, i have a client side mobile where do the requests with retrofit2, and on a request i need to send a image file and a json object. Like this:

```
RequestBody requestJson = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), new Gson().toJson(cidadao));

            MultipartBody.Part fotoBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("foto", file.getName(), requestFile);
            MultipartBody.Part jsonBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("cidadao", null, requestJson);

            Service service = CallService.createService(Service.class);
            Call<Void> cadastrarCidadao = service.postCidadao(UsuarioApplication.getInstance().getToken().getToken(),
                    jsonBody,
                    fotoBody);
            cadastrarCidadao.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.code() == 201) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                            fm.popBackStack();
                        }
                    } else {
                        APIError error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                        new Throwable(error.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("ErrorCadastro", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Toasty.error(getContext(), "Erro na conexão").show();
                }
            });
```

Service Interface:

```
package com.example.administrador.citycaremobile.Services;

import com.example.administrador.citycaremobile.Modelo.Cidadao;
import com.example.administrador.citycaremobile.Modelo.Login;

import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.PUT;
import retrofit2.http.Part;

public interface Service {

@POST("cidadao/cadastrar")
@Multipart
Call<Void> postCidadao(@Header("X-Token") String token,
                       @Part MultipartBody.Part cidadao,
                       @Part MultipartBody.Part foto);

@PUT("cidadao/put")
Call<Boolean> putUsuario(@Header("Content-type") String content,
                         @Header("X-Token") String token,
                         @Body Cidadao cidadao);

@Headers("content-type:application/json")
@GET("auth")
Call<Token> autentication();

//Login
@POST("login")
Call<Object> login(@Header("Content-type") String content,
                   @Header("X-Token") String token,
                   @Body Login login);
}
```

And on Service side, have a PHP with Slim framework, the problem is... When i try get the json, with $request->getParam(), they return to me a array with all characters, where each character is a item on that array.

Ex: if show the return $jsonParam[0], he return to me the "{", i tryed to parse all array to one String but unsucess, tryed implode method, tryed json_decode on param, but nothing work.

There are the Service side method:

```
$app -> post('/cidadao/cadastrar', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app){
        //Container do EntityManager
        $entityManager = $this -> get('em');
        $json = $request -> getParam('cidadao');

        try{
            //Instância da entidade Login
            $login = new Login();
            //recuperando o parâmetro objeto login do json
            $fk_login_cidadao = $json['fk_login_cidadao'];
            //setando valores do objeto login
            $login ->setLogin($fk_login_cidadao['login']);
            $login ->setEmail($fk_login_cidadao['email']);
            $login ->setSenha($fk_login_cidadao['senha']);
            $login ->setStatus_login($fk_login_cidadao['status_login']);
            $login ->setAsAdministrador($fk_login_cidadao['administrador']);

            //salvando login
            $entityManager->persist($login);
            $entityManager->flush();
            //buscando login recém salvo
            $loginRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Models\Entity\Login');
            //pegando login
            $loginCidadao = $loginRepository->find($login->getId_login());
            //Salvar foto
            $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
            $newimage = $files['foto'];
            if ($newimage->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $uploadFileName = $newimage->getClientFilename();
                $type = $newimage->getClientMediaType();
                $name = uniqid('img-' . date('d-m-y') . '-');
                $name .= $newimage->getClientFilename();
                //  $imgs[] = array('url' => '/Photos/' . $name);
                //local server
                $newimage->moveTo("/home/citycare/public_html/Imgs/user/$name");#/home/citycare/Imgs/User/$name
                //localdev
                $photoURL = "/home/citycare/public_html/Imgs/user/$name";#/home/citycare/Imgs/User/$name
            }
            //Instância da entidade Cidadao
            $cidadao = new Cidadao();
            //setando valores do objeto cidadao
            $cidadao ->setFk_login_cidadao($loginCidadao);
            $cidadao->setNome($request->getParam('nome'));
            $cidadao->setSexo($request->getParam('sexo'));
            $cidadao ->setSobrenome($request->getParam('sobrenome'));
            $cidadao ->setEstado($request->getParam('estado'));
            $cidadao ->setCidade($request->getParam('cidade'));
            $cidadao ->setDir_foto_usuario($request->getParam($photoURL));
            $entityManager->persist($cidadao);
            $entityManager->flush();
            //retornando confirmação do evento completo
            $return = $response->withStatus(201)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');


        } catch (Exception $ex){
            //código e mensagem do erro
            throw new Exception($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getCode());
        }
        return $return;
});
```

**The image process works fine.**

**HTTP REQUEST:**

```
10-14 03:35:38.772 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: --> POST http://servico.projetocitycare.com.br/cidadao/cadastrar http/1.1
10-14 03:35:38.773 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=58c96b8f-a56e-4b42-8052-10d48c583cc4
10-14 03:35:38.776 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 69178
10-14 03:35:38.777 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: X-Token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoicm9vdCIsInNlbmhhIjoiY2FyZWNpdHkiLCJleHAiOjE1MDc5NjMwOTUsImlwIjoiMTc3LjM3LjIyOC4xNDIifQ.ePeHn_YgmRfach6B1v4JC75147ixRwrjdoUvEjpPKRQ
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: --58c96b8f-a56e-4b42-8052-10d48c583cc4
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cidadao"
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 239
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: {"cidade":"Alto Rio Novo","estado":"Espírito Santo","fk_login_cidadao":{"administrador":false,"email":"ekekejj@mks.xkm","login":"kddjsjn","senha":"jskeieej","status_login":true},"nome":"neenenem","sexo":"Masculino","sobrenome":"memekekk"}
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: --58c96b8f-a56e-4b42-8052-10d48c583cc4
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foto"; filename="cropped83912673.jpg"
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 68558
10-14 03:35:38.788 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: ������JFIF����������������C��
10-14 03:35:38.800 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: --58c96b8f-a56e-4b42-8052-10d48c583cc4--
10-14 03:35:38.800 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: --> END POST (69178-byte body)
```

**HTTP RESPONSE:**

```
10-14 03:35:39.675 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: <-- 500 Internal Server Error http://servico.projetocitycare.com.br/cidadao/cadastrar (874ms)
10-14 03:35:39.676 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Server: nginx
10-14 03:35:39.676 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 14 Oct 2017 06:35:39 GMT
10-14 03:35:39.676 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
10-14 03:35:39.677 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
10-14 03:35:39.677 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
10-14 03:35:39.678 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: Upgrade: h2,h2c
10-14 03:35:39.685 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp:     {"message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO login (email, login, senha, status_login, administrador) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [\"{\", \"{\", \"ew==\", \"{\", \"{\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '{' for key 'UNIQ_AA08CB10E7927C74'"}
10-14 03:35:39.686 19151-9871/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (310-byte body)
```

Json sended is like this:

```
    {"cidade":"Brasília",
     "estado":"Distrito Federal",
     "fk_login_cidadao":{ "administrador":false,
                          "email":"b@b.com",
                          "login":"jhon",
                          "senha":"182873728192",
                          "status_login":true},
     "nome":"Jhon",
     "sexo":"Masculino",
     "sobrenome":"James"}
```

Comment: I need to take a look at your postCidadao function and interface code. Add it to the question. thanks.

Comment: Uptaded. The function code run from retrofit, so i just implements interface with Services.

Comment: I need to take a look at your request, post a request to https://requestb.in/14i0kfg1  and leave a message here when you have done so.

Comment: I uptaded the question with the request and response from server, to do a post on your link from my app I need change many things to do that. I get the request and response from okHttp::LoggingInterceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many tries, using var_dump() on $json i saw the request isn't decoded by framework, i don't know why, so i needed to do manually the decode and work with Object instead of Array. Finally the API side code stayed like this:

```
$app ->post('/cidadao/cadastrar', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app){
        //Container do EntityManager
        $entityManager = $this -> get('em');

        $json = $request->getParam('cidadao');
        $json = json_decode($json);


        try{
            //InstÃ¢ncia da entidade Login
            $login = new Login();
            //recuperando o parÃ¢metro objeto login do json
            $fk_login_cidadao = $json -> fk_login_cidadao;
            //setando valores do objeto login
            $login ->setLogin($fk_login_cidadao -> login);
            $login ->setEmail($fk_login_cidadao -> email);
            $login ->setSenha($fk_login_cidadao -> senha);
            $login ->setStatus_login($fk_login_cidadao -> status_login);
            $login ->setAsAdministrador($fk_login_cidadao -> administrador);

            //salvando login
            $entityManager->persist($login);
            $entityManager->flush();
            //buscando login recÃ©m salvo
            $loginRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('App\Models\Entity\Login');
            //pegando login
            $loginCidadao = $loginRepository->find($login->getId_login());
            //Salvar foto
            $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
            $newimage = $files['foto'];
            if ($newimage->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $uploadFileName = $newimage->getClientFilename();
                $type = $newimage->getClientMediaType();
                $name = uniqid('img-' . date('d-m-y') . '-');
                $name .= $newimage->getClientFilename();
                //  $imgs[] = array('url' => '/Photos/' . $name);
                //local server
                $newimage->moveTo("/home/citycare//imgs/$name");#/home/citycare/Imgs/User/$name
                //localdev
                $photoURL = "/home/citycare//imgs/$name";#/home/citycare/Imgs/User/$name
            }
            //InstÃ¢ncia da entidade Cidadao
            $cidadao = new Cidadao();
            //setando valores do objeto cidadao
            $cidadao ->setFk_login_cidadao($loginCidadao);
            $cidadao->setNome($json -> nome);
            $cidadao->setSexo($json -> sexo);
            $cidadao ->setSobrenome($json -> sobrenome);
            $cidadao ->setEstado($json -> estado);
            $cidadao ->setCidade($json -> cidade);
            $cidadao ->setDir_foto_usuario($photoURL);
            $entityManager->persist($cidadao);
            $entityManager->flush();
            //retornando confirmaÃ§Ã£o do evento completo
            $return = $response->withStatus(201)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');


        } catch (Exception $ex){
            //cÃ³digo e mensagem do erro
            throw new Exception($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getCode());
        }
        return $return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request body is sound for the most part, except for this: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` I don't understand why retrofit2 is adding that to the `form-data`. However, I don't think that's the error you are experiencing.

At fist I thought PHP was not parsing the `form-data` correctly because of that extra bit. But then I realized you are parsing JSON and accessing it as an Array. Your json string is an object and will be interpreted as such by the PHP JSON decoder.

So in conclusion, you should be accessing the values of your data (json) object like this: `$json->fk_login_cidadao` and not like this: `$json['fk_login_cidadao']`. That also goes for the rest of your value and key pairs.

If you want to test my theory, simply log or write the contents of the param `$request -> getParam('cidadao')` to file.

Comment: i did some changes, and now the form-data not go with binary, but now service say : 204, No content, so the ParsedBody is empty...

Comment: $request->getParsedBody() does not work with multipart/form-data, so remove it and it's if else clause.

Comment: I removed, but now i cant get the json data, when a try getParam() from the request they me return null... https://imgur.com/a/szMf6 ::: API side.

Comment: Exception returned from API to client : 10-14 01:49:33.403 28338-1425/com.example.administrador.citycaremobile D/OkHttp:     {"message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO login (email, login, senha, status_login, administrador) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, \"\", null, null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null"}

Comment: Check your request body since you made changes. Maybe something is not right. Plus try to use $_POST['cidadao'] or $_REQUEST['cidadao'] for debugging purposes.

Comment: I uptaded the question with the new codes, new request and response result from request. I left the Content-Transfer-Encoding and set the json with a simple requestBody without name, like a application/json common post, but I failed when try to get the json data.

Comment: No it won't work. I don't know what you are doing, but the body content should be of type Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cidadao". Anything else will just not work. Roll it back where it was before. Plus Json should not be content-transfer-encoding: binary. Put back the @Part annotation.

Comment: $fk_login_cidadao = $_REQUEST['cidadao']. do that also.

Comment: getParam('cidadao') do same than $_REQUEST, i rolled back, but the problem on decode json persist.

Comment: Then the problem lies with the Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary.

Comment: Yes, I think. When I do json_encode on request Json, they return something like that:  "{\"cidade\":\"Alto Rio Novo\",\"estado\":\"Esp\u00edrito Santo\",\"fk_login_cidadao\":{\"administrador\":false,\"email\":\"ekekejj@mks.xkm\",\"login\":\"kddjsjn\",\"senha\":\"jskeieej\",\"status_login\":true},\"nome\":\"neenenem\",\"sexo\":\"Masculino\",\"sobrenome\":\"memekekk\"}", why the content have that "\" ?

Comment: Then try without json_decode. It's possible it's already decoded.

Comment: When the API get Json request, they automatically encode, but they encoding wrong, why... i don't know